# Testing piped/nested HttpClient in Angular service not completes

Tags: angular, jasmine, observable, karma-jasmine, angular8

I would like to test a piped HttpClient call, but it seems http call not completes in time and there is no response.

**configuration.service.ts**

```js
public loadData() {
   return this.configurationService.getAppConfig().pipe(
      switchMap(appConfig => this.http.get<string[]>("url"))
   );
}
```

**configuration.service.spec.ts**

```js
let service: CustomService;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            CustomService,
            { provide: ConfigurationService, useClass: MockedConfigurationService }
        ],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });

    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(ConfigurationService);
});

it("should make a get request for loadData", () => {
    service.loadData().subscribe(data => {
        // This is not called
        console.log(data);
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne("url");
    req.flush(["my.data"]);

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");

    httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

Everything is working fine if I'm just returning the request like

```js
return this.http.get<string[]>("url");
```

I have tried using manullay created/completed Observables also, but subscribe not called for httpClient:

```js
const appConfig$ = this.configurationService.getAppConfig();

return new Observable(observer => {
    appConfig$.subscribe(appConfig => {
        this.http.get<string[]>("url").subscribe(
            result => {
                observer.next(result);
                observer.complete();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks like the test case is finishing before the httpClient is able to complete.

Comment: whats there in `MockedConfigurationService ` , can u share that please

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your `MockedConfigurationService` is not accurate. Can we see it?

Try

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
class MockedConfigurationService {
  getAppConfig() {
    return of('hello world'); // or whatever you would like.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I figured it out.

The problem was, that multiple async calls caused the http content flush run earlier than the call itself.

So I'm using fakeAsync and there is a flush() before flushing the real data, which is letting the httpClient to open request first.

```js
it("should make a get request for loadData", fakeAsync(() => {
    service.loadData().subscribe(data => {
        // This is called
        console.log(data);
    });

    flush();

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne("url");
    req.flush(["my.data"]);

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");

    httpTestingController.verify();
}));
```

Maybe there are better solutions, I'm open to them.